# CakePHP route broken

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I need to define a route for viewing posts on my website and I'm having some trouble.

The URLs that I need to catch are in this format:

```
http://mysite.com/category/10-post-slug
```

I've made this route which doesn't work:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:category/:id-:slug', 
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), 
    array('category' => '[a-z0-9-]+', 'id' => '[0-9+]', 'slug' => '[a-z0-9-]+')
);
```

Instead of going to the `view` action of the `posts` controller, it instead goes to another route defined later on in `routes.php`:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:parent/:category', 
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'viewCategory'), 
    array('parent' => '[a-z0-9-]+', 'category' => '[a-z0-9-]+')
);
```

Why does my first route not match the url `/category/10-post-slug`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your route doesn't mean what you think

```
Router::connect(
    '/:category/:id-:slug', 
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), 
    array('category' => '[a-z0-9-]+', 'id' => '[0-9+]', 'slug' => '[a-z0-9-]+')
);
                                                   ^
```

The pattern for valid ids that you have is any single character from the following list:

```
0123456789+
```

So it will not match any id higher than 9. Instead you need:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:category/:id-:slug', 
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), 
    array('category' => '[a-z0-9-]+', 'id' => '[0-9]+', 'slug' => '[a-z0-9-]+')
);
                                                    ^
```

Which will match any number.